# Java class getdata

Tags: java

I can't find the problem. When i use the class
and use first setpostcode to 5000. and then getUrl i get still 1000
in my url idk why. when i debug the postcode is changed to 5000 but when i print the url i get 1000.

```
public class weer {

  private int  postcode = 1000;
  private String url = "http://www.meteo.be/services/widget/.?postcode="+  postcode +"&nbDay=2&type=4&lang=nl&bgImageId=1&bgColor=567cd2&scrolChoice=0&colorTempMax=A5D6FF&colorTempMin=fffff";



public int getPostcode() {
    return postcode;
}

public void setPostcode(int postcode) {
    this.postcode = postcode;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

}

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    weer w = new weer();
    w.setPostcode(5000);
    System.out.println(w.getPostcode());
    System.out.println(w.getUrl());

}
```

Comment: Hint: please read about java naming conventions. Classes go UpperCase, variables go camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL member variable is declared and initialized once upon creation of the class instance. It starts at 1000 and never changes.

Updates to one value aren't reflected to the other.

You don't really don't need the URL member variable if you only are updating the postcode, just change the getter to

```
return  "http://www.meteo.be/services/widget/.?postcode="+  postcode +"&nbDay=2&type=4&lang=nl&bgImageId=1&bgColor=567cd2&scrolChoice=0&colorTempMax=A5D6FF&colorTempMin=fffff";
```

Or, if you do need the setter for the URL, update the other setter

```
public void setPostcode(int postcode) {
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.url = "http://www.meteo.be/services/widget/.?postcode="+  postcode +"&nbDay=2&type=4&lang=nl&bgImageId=1&bgColor=567cd2&scrolChoice=0&colorTempMax=A5D6FF&colorTempMin=fffff";
}
```